# Why the client can't information from subscription?

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, websocket, sockjs

The project is contained WebSocketConfiguration with endpoint 'ws' and simple broker prefix '/topic'.

```
@Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry)
    {
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry)
    {
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("").
                enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
    }
```

When I call the post method ('/action') from the backend service in angular component, the message convert and send to the destination '/topic/test'.

```
 @PostMapping("/action/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Information> action(HttpSession httpSession, @PathVariable(name = "id") String gameId,
                                              @Valid  @RequestParam("action") Action action) {
        try
        {
            Information information = gameService.handle(httpSession.getId(),
                    UUID.fromString(gameId), action);
            messagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic/test", "go");
            return new ResponseEntity<>(information, HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (HttpClientErrorException e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(e.getStatusCode());
        }
    }
```

In the angular component the result of websocket don't update, as if the message doesn't send to destination.
The connect in the constructor of component:

```
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private gameService: GameService) {

    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.id = params['id'];
    });
    const socket = new SockJS(`http://192.168.0.16:8080/ws`);
    let stomp = Stomp.over(socket);
    stomp.connect('', function(frame) {
      stomp.subscribe(`/topic/test`, res => {
        console.log(res);

      });
    });
  }
```

**UPDATE**:
*I have a solution. I just change the endpoint to 'socket' from 'ws', and it's work. I don't know why. Whi is it work? This is a very funny situation for me and I want to know why.*

Comment: Please include the relevant code as a [mcve] in the question itself, not only on an external site.

Comment: the documentation states the following:  `SockJS is a browser JavaScript library that provides a WebSocket-like object. SockJS gives you a coherent, cross-browser, Javascript API which creates a low latency, full duplex, cross-domain communication channel between the browser and the web server.

Under the hood SockJS tries to use native WebSockets first. If that fails it can use a variety of browser-specific transport protocols and presents them through WebSocket-like abstractions.`   I guess it just falls back to what it actually can do which is not WS at this moment.   any debugging?